# ng-change event not working on text box with date picker in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to call ng-change event after select date form the date picker but right now this event is not working and not getting any error in console so how can understand where is problem in this code.

here my html text box :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="txtdate" ng-model="txtdate" ng-change="onChange()"/>
```

here my angular.js code :

```
$scope.onChange = function () {            
       alert('test');
    };
```

here is my boostrap date picker injecter:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MMM DD YYYY',            
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
            down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
            previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
            next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
            today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
            clear: 'fa fa-trash',
            close: 'fa fa-remove'
        }
    });
});
```

I am put ng-controller and ng-app propare in my html page but don't know what is missing and where is error so any one can help me please.

Comment: please let me know which datepicker are you using for date ?

Comment: @ManojPatidar i am using boostrap date picker form the one small template please let me know where is problem.

Comment: can you add your code to inject bootstab datepicker in angular js ?

Comment: @ManojPatidar yes i edited my question in few mintues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems to be working fine. check your module and controller is define and link properly to html file.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  
$scope.onChange = function () {            
       alert('test');
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="txtdate" ng-model="txtdate" ng-change="onChange()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: still same issue. yes i propare added module and controller in my html code.

Comment: hi can you know about this "how to add custom pagination in datatable with angularjs?" i have alerdy added this question on stack overflow.